# Want to display n number of google map in one page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

i want to create one textbox which accept city or country name and when user click on button the map will display and load another textbox control which accept another location and the second map will display this process is want to continue at n number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the techniques from several places:

1. Simple geocoding (the input box that maps what user types): https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple
2. Going from 2 simultaneous maps: http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.in/2011/06/two-maps-on-same-page-side-by-side.html to 4 simultaneous maps: http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.in/2011/07/four-maps-on-same-page-playing-with.html and up to n simultaneous maps

You're going to have to instantiate new divs (perhaps using jQuery) and instantiate new Google Map instances for each new map.  The center point of each independent map will be defined by the values returned from the Geocoding API.  You'll have to have a data structure of some sort to keep up with the map instances, and a method to organize the newly created divs to tell the Google Maps API where to draw the map tiles.

Comment: i want to aceept multiple location and show multiple map in one page. i.e user first enter new york then first map is display then he enter another name then second map is display